Undefined name 'FontWeight'
I'm getting the following errors. I have confirmed Flutter SDK is installed correctly.
Undefined name 'FontWeight'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.
I tried flutter doctor, checking to see if Dart and Flutter were installed correctly. Confirmed I have the latest version. I checked this file pubspec.yaml
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'profile.dart';

class FindVendorsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final String currentUserId = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _getVendorsFromMyEvents() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('applications')
        .where('organizerId', isEqualTo: currentUserId)
        .where('status', isEqualTo: 'approved')
        .snapshots();
  }

  Stream<QuerySnapshot> _getAllVendors() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').where('isVendor', isEqualTo: true).snapshots();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Find Vendors'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'Vendors from My Events',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _getVendorsFromMyEvents(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }

                var applications = snapshot.data!.docs;
                var vendorIds = applications.map((doc) => doc['userId'] as String).toList();

                return vendorIds.isEmpty
                    ? Center(child: Text('No vendors found.'))
                    : StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                            .collection('users')
                            .where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: vendorIds)
                            .snapshots(),
                        builder: (context, vendorSnapshot) {
                          if (!vendorSnapshot.hasData) {
                            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                          }

                          var vendors = vendorSnapshot.data!.docs;

                          return ListView.builder(
                            shrinkWrap: true,
                            physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                            itemCount: vendors.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              var vendor = vendors[index];
                              var vendorData = vendor.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

                              return ListTile(
                                title: Text('${vendorData['firstName']} ${vendorData['lastName']}'),
                                subtitle: Text(vendorData['store'] ?? 'No store information'),
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => ProfileScreen(userId: vendor.id),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        },
                      );
              },
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                'All Vendors',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
            ),
            StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: _getAllVendors(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                }

                var vendors = snapshot.data!.docs;

                if (vendors.isEmpty) {
                  return Center(child: Text('No vendors found.'));
                }

                return ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                  itemCount: vendors.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    var vendor = vendors[index];
                    var vendorData = vendor.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

                    return ListTile(
                      title: Text('${vendorData['firstName']} ${vendorData['lastName']}'),
                      subtitle: Text(vendorData['store'] ?? 'No store information'),
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => ProfileScreen(userId: vendor.id),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

